# Crystal Reports: ошибка "Access Violation in module p2bxbse.dll"

Tags: delphi, dbf, crystalreport

При попытке открыть отчёт Crystal Reports из приложения, написанного на Delphi, возникает ошибка "Access violation at address in module p2bxbse.dll". Отчёт открывается через ActiveX компонент, версия Crystal Reports - <strike>11.5</strike> 6 - выяснилось, что ошибка происходит только с небольшой частью отчётов, которые до сих пор на 6 версии. Отчёт представлен набором из rpt и нескольких dbf файлов.
Возникает очень редко, но в разных случаях: и 32, и 64 разрядные Windows от XP до 7. Воспроизвести пока не удалось. Даже после попытки испортить установку CR такой ошибки не возникало. Найти решение тоже пока не удалось. Похожая проблема была связана с настройками DEP в Windows, но в данном случае те же действия проблему не решили.

Подскажите, пожалуйста: сталкивались ли вы с такой проблемой? Какие возможны пути решения?

**Upd. 20.02.2016.** Пробуем перевести этот отчет на Crystal Reports 11.5, с которым такой проблемы ещё не возникало. Отпишусь по результатам.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь инструментом `madExcept` от [madshi.net](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) (бесплатно для некоммерческого использования). В отчете будет виден стек вызовов каждого потока с указанием номера строки в исходном коде в момент возникновения ошибки.

Comment: Разве madExcept сможет заглянуть в стороннюю DLL?

Comment: Ошибка точно возникает внутри сторонней DLL, поэтому этот инструмент вряд ли поможет. За совет спасибо, попробую. Любая новая информация в этому случае будет полезной.

Comment: Тот факт, что ошибка возникает в сторонней библиотеке, еще не говорит о том, что там баг. Может вы не правильно ее используете. Я бы в первую очередь искал ошибки в своем коде.

Comment: Приложение корректно работает на нескольких тысячах рабочих мест и примерно на десятке возникает эта ошибка. Скорее всего проблема в окружении, в настройках ПО или ОС. Но вот в чём именно - это и есть вопрос. Перепробовал многое: настройки DEP, групповые политики, права пользователя, права доступа на папки - пока не помогло.